# Python 3 with large integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use Python to handle some large integers (64-bit, unsigned). I'm trying to convert a string of values to integers. However my Python3 gave me incorrect results. 
For example, if I convert an input string of "12736193479609682490" to integer, the result is not what I expected:

```
a = '12736193479609682490'
b = int(float(a))

>>>b
12736193479609681920
```

I'm usng Python 3.4.0 under ubuntu 12.04-64bit. What should I do to make a correct conversion? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't convert to float first.

```
>>> int("12736193479609682490")
12736193479609682490
```

That number is too big to store in a float accurately!

Comment: As far as I can remember, when I used the direct conversion from string to int, Python gave me error that this was not a valid operation. Since which version, python starts to support that?

Comment: I think you are remembering inaccurately - possibly you had a string like `"123.0"` which you can not convert directly to int like this.

Answer (score 3):

Don't convert to `float` first, that's where you're losing the accuracy.

```
b = int(a)
```

A float starts failing after it gets above 9007199254740992. Odd values at first, then more and more as it gets larger.